# Steampunk book about alternate universe World War I

Tags: story-identification, steampunk

I picked up a book a long time ago in a library and I want to read it now, but I can't remember the name. It's about WWI except the US/UK use genetically modified animals to fight, while Germany/Austria uses steampunk machines. I think it also had pictures and involved a Prince of some kind.

Comment: Hope I guessed right about "AU WWI" in the title of your question. Roll back my edit if it was supposed to mean something like "Australian Walking While Intoxicated".

Comment: Just hitting on 'steampunk wwi novel' as keywords, is it [Leviathan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan_%28Westerfeld_novel%29)?

Comment: @gowenfawr - The presence of a prince as the main character and "machines vs genetically engineered animals" would seem to clinch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[The Leviathan Trilogy](http://www.goodreads.com/series/46550-leviathan)* by Scott Westerfield.

> Prince Aleksander, would-be heir to the Austro-Hungarian throne, is on
>   the run. His own people have turned on him. His title is worthless.
>   All he has is a battletorn war machine and a loyal crew of men.
>
> Deryn Sharp is a commoner, disguised as a boy in the British Air
>   Service. She's a brilliant airman. But her secret is in constant
>   danger of being discovered.
>
> With World War I brewing, Alek and Deryn's paths cross in the most
>   unexpected way…taking them on a fantastical, around-the-world
>   adventure that will change both their lives forever.

...

> Young adult fiction set in alternate World War I has German Central
>   Powers (Clankers) using mechanized war machines opposed by British
>   Entente Powers (Darwinists) who fabricate living creatures
>   genetically. Heroes are teens Aleksander, son of Archduke Franz
>   Ferdinand, and Deryn, Scottish girl with dreams of joining the British
>   Air Service with her brother.

[image]

Comment: I think that's it.